# How can I create a python datetime with trimmed milliseconds (3 digits) AND utc offset?

Tags: python, datetime

I'd like to get date with 3 digit milliseconds and UTC offset, for example:

```
'2022-06-27T14:51:23.230+00:00'
```

I have the following code:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%f%z')
created = datetime.datetime.strptime(now,'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%f%z').isoformat()
```

The issue is that I am getting the following format:

```
'2022-06-27T14:51:23.230061+00:00'
```

Obviously I cannot cut the last 3 digits using [:-3] as I will cut the utc offset and will end up with:

```
'2022-06-27T14:51:23.230061+00'
```

Is there any other way to tell datetime to return only 3 digits for milliseconds or trim it in any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `timespec` to `'milliseconds'` when calling [`datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

created = datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
```

Output:

```
2022-06-27T14:51:23.230+00:00
```